# Managed Property name from site column name

Tags: 2013, site-column, managed-property, search-api

Is there a function of SharePoint API that gets as input a name of a site column and returns the name of the corresponding ManagedProperty?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for something similar. I will try to decompile the Microsoft code, but for now this article is helpful:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/automatically-created-managed-properties-in-sharepoint

Comment: You can add some brief description from the link.